# Is dovecot compatible with Outlook's "Leave on server for X days" setting?

Tags: dovecot, outlook

I've got a linux box running dovecot/postfix. I was surprised to learn that a client that had many GBs of email was running POP3. I thought they must have been using IMAP. But it turns out the server was not removing the email from the user accounts as requested by the user in their MS Outlook setting.

I also discovered that if they turn off the "leave on server" option, the email is properly removed from the server.

I know this is not how POP3 is supposed to work, but is there a way to get dovecot to honor the user's settings in Outlook?

I googled around but found nothing so I'm here.

EDIT: Using maildir format.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that I'm not familiar with dovecot/postfix, check if the outlook configuration are correct. [POP Account: How Do I Set My Mail Client To Leave A Copy Of Messages On The Server?](https://help.redtailtechnology.com/hc/en-us/articles/203966710-POP-Account-How-do-I-set-my-mail-client-to-leave-a-copy-of-messages-on-the-server-)